# JavaScript code for window.speechSynthesis not working from localhost

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, text-to-speech

Following code works fine in Chrome DevTools but when I run this through localhost `allVoices` returns an empty array.

```
tts = window.speechSynthesis

// from here code only works if put into DevTools, not from file or localhost
allVoices = tts.getVoices()

console.log(allVoices) // gives empty array
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Chrome getVoices() returns empty, then there's an event when the voices are ready, onvoiceschanged, which accepts a callback.

Your commands work in DevTools because by the time you've typed 'allVoices = tts.getVoices()' the voices have already arrived and are available.

However other browsers e.g. Safari return voices synchronously and there's no need for a callback.

Therefore the best code seems to be:

```
let voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
  if (voices.length) {
    resolve(voices);
    return;
  }
  speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = () => {
    voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
    if (voices.length) resolve(voices);
  };
```